# Performance penalty for undefined arguments

Tags: javascript, performance, arguments

I quite often have optional arguments in functions, but some testing is showing a huge performance hit for them in firefox and safari (70-95%). Strangely, if I pass in the literal value *undefined* then there is no penalty. What could be happening here? I wouldn't have thought that it was a scope chain issue as they are inherently local to the function. Am I to start passing *undefined* into every optional argument?

jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/function-undefined-args/2

Comment: @MattWhipple - That's an interesting post, but what does it have to do with OP's question? (Nice question, by the way, @robC.)

Comment: This is an interesting find. Before you change all your code to fill all arguments, I'd check to see if there's an open bug report for those JS implementations, and if not file one.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the runtime is inlining the functions when there's a parameter count match, but running the function as an actual function call otherwise.  The fact that nothing makes any use of the function return value may mean that the runtime does *nothing at all* when the parameters are fully supplied.

Comment: @TedHopp - whoops, need to annotate my bookmarks more carefully.

Comment: [Here's a test](http://jsperf.com/function-undefined-args/5) that makes use of the return values, to avoid the problem of the optimizer simply skipping the whole thing.  It also uses non-constants, because the optimizer may also fold those.  It's important to make sure that tests like these are realistic and not corrupted by optimizer effects that won't happen in real code.  Still, it's clear that Firefox at least appears to give up on inlining if there's a parameter count mismatch.

Comment: If the function has some side-effect or its code is something less trivial than a simple return statement, the optimizer will be way less likely to inline it, and I bet in that case the difference would be minimal if even detectable at all. In fact the missing-param cases might actually be slightly faster!

Comment: @Pointy, thanks I see, will try refactoring that myself. Is it possible that in your test you are accessing the DOM which is more expensive, flattening out the result through less iterations?

Comment: The DOM access just happens at setup time.  There's still a pretty significant performance hit for Firefox. I did that to try and keep the optimizer from doing constant folding.

Comment: @Pointy yes my bad. Sorry what do those vars add to the test?

Comment: Well the point is that you don't want the optimizer to figure out that it can just add up the constants for you and skip the function call entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a function like this:

```
function threeArgs(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}
```

that's called like this:

```
threeArgs(1, 2, 3);
```

the optimizer is free to make the choice to generate no code at all.  It's fairly easy for it to determine that there are no side effects, because the function simply references its parameter values and returns the result of a simple expression. Since the return value is ignored, there's no reason for the runtime to do anything at all.

Beyond that, if the code were:

```
something += threeArgs(1, 2, 3);
```

the optimizer might decide to generate code roughly equivalent to:

```
something += 6;
```

Why? Because the call was made with numeric constants, and it can safely fold those at code generation time. It might be conservative on that, because numbers are weird, but here they're all integers so it could well do this. Even if it didn't, it could safely inline the function:

```
something += 1 + 2 + 3;
```

When there's a parameter missing, however, it may be that the optimizers bail out and generate a real function call. For such a simple function, the overhead of the function call could easily account for a large difference in performance.

By using variables instead of constants in a test, and by actually using the return value of the function, you can "confuse" the optimizer and keep it from skipping the call or pre-computing the result, but you can't keep it from inlining.  I still think that your result is interesting for that reason: it exposes the fact that (as of today anyway) those optimizers are sensitive to the way that functions are invoked.

Comment: This seems like a plausible explanation, but how do we know this is really what is happening?

Comment: The results for FF and latest Chrome are so far ahead of the field that it can only really be down to optimizations. The function call that carries a penalty is actually around the same performance as other non optimised browsers.

Comment: "When there's a parameter missing, however, it may be that the optimizers bail out" - could you elaborate on why that is? If an argument is missing, it's guaranteed to be undefined, so to me it seems it would just inline `1 + 2 + undefined`.

Comment: @pimvdb I agree it's odd; I'm really just guessing here, as it's clear that it does make a difference. I have no informed idea why the optimizer would work that way however.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't know for sure; it could well be something completely different.  It's pretty clear that *something* is going on, however.

Answer (score 2):

I think what could explain the performance difference is the way arguments are passed to a function object: via the `arguments` object. When not passing any arguments, JS will start by scanning the arguments object for any of the given arguments, when those are undefined, The `arguments` prototype chain will be scanned, all the way up to `Object.prototype`. If those all lack the desired property, JS will return `undefined`. Whereas, passing undefined explicitly, sets it as a property directly on the arguments object:

```
function foo(arg)
{
    console.log(arguments.hasOwnProperty('0'));
}
foo();//false'
foo('bar');//true
foo(undefined);//true
```

I gather that's the reason why passing undefined explicitly tends to be faster.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but it seems to me that since the "arg" symbol is declared in the formal parameter list it will *always* be a local reference.

Comment: Perhaps, but changing the function to `console.log(arg === arguments[0]);` and calling `foo(new Date())` logs true, so both reference the exact same thing. I'd actually say that args is a local reference to a property of the local `arguments` object. Scope scanning aside, the prototype arguments still holds, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh yes, I agree on that - the `arguments` object is bizarre. I am not sure exactly how it would affect this, is what I meant.  In other words, since "arg" is a formal parameter, then its value is *always* the value of `arguments[0]`, whether that's `undefined` or not.

Comment: Damn and blast, again, I end up writing half a bloody book, and you manage to recap it in a single comment :)