# Underscore.js wrapped callbacks efficiency

Tags: javascript, performance, underscore.js

I have a  question about the [annotated underscore.js source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-12):

It says:

> Internal function that returns an efficient (for current engines) version of the passed-in callback, to be repeatedly applied in other Underscore functions.

```
var createCallback = function(func, context, argCount) {
    if (context === void 0) return func;
    switch (argCount == null ? 3 : argCount) {
        case 1: return function(value) {
            return func.call(context, value);
        };
        case 2: return function(value, other) {
            return func.call(context, value, other);
        };
        case 3: return function(value, index, collection) {
            return func.call(context, value, index, collection);
        };
        case 4: return function(accumulator, value, index, collection) {
            return func.call(context, accumulator, value, index, collection);
        };
    }
    return function() {
        return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
};
```

Explicitly, how is reached the efficiency in this block of code ?

Cause I see that with the wrapper, is created one more level of indirection and the scope chain grows one more level two.

I need to understand how is reached the efficiency, in order to apply this tricks in my own js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some shuffling of argument order but some of the cases are actually equivalent if later arguments were left empty. I think that logic also probably makes the callback play nicely with browser optimisations. For example, if the return value is predictable then the result may be inlined rather than calling the actual function each time.
Here is a related discussion about performance and arguments, where testing showed some big speed differences:

[Performance penalty for undefined arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662497/performance-penalty-for-undefined-arguments)

Comment: Thanks robC, I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Hi robC, I think that the decision to write the code like it is written in createCallback undescore internal function is for the reason explained in the link "Performance penalty for undefined arguments". Never the less, I run your test in http://jsperf.com/function-undefined-args/2 and saw only little or none performance improvements. Thanks!

Comment: @pelicanorojo sure, it depends on the browser, you can see that firefox 14 or Safari 7 show a difference for that test in the results graph. BTW you should upvote useful answers, and accept a correct answer by clicking the tick.

Comment: Yes, but my reputation is 11 and I need 15 for that!

Comment: @pelicanorojo ah sorry, well I think that you can still mark the accepted answer, please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When using the underscore iterator functions (such as `_.map`, `_.reduce` and `_.each`), the callbacks that are provided offer different arguments. For example:

```
_.map(list, function(value, key, list) {});

_.reduce(list, function(memo, num, list) {});
```

The `createCallback` is a convenience function used internally by underscore to define the order of the arguments in these iterator functions. If we look at the `_.reduce` function we can see this line:

```
iteratee = createCallback(iteratee, context, 4);
```

Which will output:

```
func.call(context, accumulator, value, index, collection);
```

Where `func` is the iterator function provided to `_.reduce`

Comment: Thanks Jivings for your answer too. I will analyze both and then will vote.

Comment: Sorry, but I saw this on the commented code. And I understand the code. But your answer don't say why there is an efficiency improvement. I am not sure, but I think that the reason why the coder do this, is for the reason that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662497/performance-penalty-for-undefined-arguments  . Thanks!